# Python click on coordinates in an active window only

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, click, cursor-position

I want to click with my mouse button on a certain point but only in active window.
Let's say my active window's size is 720x1280  and I want to click on `(520, 1080)` point in this window. How do I do it?
I've only managed to click on this point but it was the point on the screen not in an active window.
My code is:

```py
def click(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0)
```

I'm clueless and I'm not very familiar with stuff like win32 libraries (con, api etc.)

Comment: In case you are trying to automate a 'regular' application, use UI Automation instead.

Comment: What do you mean by 'regular' application and 'UI Automation'?

Comment: @Qiasm You can answer at least one of those questions yourself using websearch. Doing so will save you time.

Comment: A 'regular' application is one that is built using standard UI components, as opposed to applications (like games) that implement their own custom UI. Custom UI's usually do not implement the interfaces required to use UI Automation.

Comment: Ummm... It's not a regular application then. Let's say It's just a window. Like a web browser or file explorer or even a game. Just a window.

Comment: A web browser is a regular application, that implements UI Automation interfaces. Windows' File Explorer is a regular application, that implements UI Automation interfaces. If you fail to understand and convey your problem, we cannot help you.

Comment: The target application is important. I'm not sure why you won't say what it is.

Comment: It's a Bluestacks app. A game in it to be exact.

Comment: BlueStacks has [script game control](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033855291-How-to-use-scripts-on-BlueStacks-) built in.

Comment: But I want to click with my mouse. Like a normal click.

Answer (score 0):

There are three coordinates: screen coordinates, active window coordinates and client area coordinates of the active window.

If you want to click a point which has a relative position (`(720-520)`, `(1280-1080)`) to the active window, you first retrieves the dimensions of the bounding rectangle of the specified window using [`GetWindowRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect). (The dimensions are given in screen coordinates.) Then plus the above offset (`200`, `200`).

If you want to click a point which has a relative position (`200`, `200`) to the client area of active window, you first retrieves the coordinates of a window's client area using [`GetClientRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclientrect). Then plus the above offset (`200`, `200`). Since [`SetCursorPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursorpos) use screen coordinates, so you need convert coordinates of the client area of the active window to screen coordinates using [`ClientToScreen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-clienttoscreen).

At last, [`mouse_event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function has been superseded. Use [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead.

Comment: I really don't get it at all and the links are for C++ not for Python. I want to click on `(520, 1080)` point in an active window not `((720 - 520), (1280 - 1080))`.

Comment: You actually call C++ winapi via Python and you can refer to official documents for how to use these API in Python. As you have already found that use (520, 1080) point it **on the screen not in an active window** because you have't convent the point coordinate on the window to on the screen.